# Haskell - sortBy function

Tags: haskell

I have a list of vectors. But now I want to sort this list of vectors by their length, using the sortBy function. What I have already is:

```
import Data.List

vectorLength::(Int,Int)->Float
vectorLength(x,y) = sqrt(fromIntegral ((x^2)+(y^2)))

sortVectors::[(Int, Int)]->[(Int, Int)]
sortVectors list = sortBy(map vectorLength list) list

main = do
    print(map vectorLength [(1,4), (2,6), (-2, -8), (3, -4)])
    print(sortVectors[(1,4), (2,6), (-2,-8), (3, -4)])
```

The vectorLength function does work.

```
map vectorLength [(1,4), (2,6), (-2,-8),(3,-4)]   
output: [4.1231055, 6.3245554, 8.246211, 5.0]
```

I want when calling the following function

```
sortVectors [(1,4), (2,6), (-2,-8), (3,-4)]  
output: [(-2,-8), (2,6), (3,-4), (1,4)]
```

But I get the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `(Int, Int)' with actual type `[a0]'
    Expected type: (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int) -> Ordering
      Actual type: [a0] -> [b0]
    In the return type of a call of `map'
    In the first argument of `sortBy', namely `(map vectorLength list)'
    In the expression: sortBy (map vectorLength list) list
```

---

**Thank you for your help.
Here is my solution**

```
import Data.List

vectorLength::(Int,Int)->Float
vectorLength(x,y) = sqrt(fromIntegral ((x^2)+(y^2)))

sortVectors::[(Int, Int)]->[(Int, Int)]
sortVectors list = rever(sortBy compareVectors list)

rever::[(Int, Int)]->[(Int, Int)]
rever [] = []
rever (x:xs) = rever xs ++ [x]

compareVectors::(Int, Int) ->(Int, Int) ->Ordering
compareVectors(a,b) (c,d) 
    | vectorLength(a,b) < vectorLength(c,d) = LT
    | vectorLength(a,b) > vectorLength(c,d) = GT

main = do
    print(map vectorLength [(1,4), (2,6), (-2, -8), (3, -4)])
    print(sortVectors[(1,4), (2,6), (-2,-8), (3, -4)])
```

Comment: "Thank you for your help. Here is my solution" -- answers should be posted in the answer field as a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), rather than edited into the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just write:

```
sortBy (comparing vectorLength) ....
```

You gave a list as first element to sortBy, but a function is required.

To write it out, what you want is:

```
sortBy comparVectors listofvectors
    where comparVectors a b = vectorLength a `compare` vectorLength b
```

Comment: Which can also be written `comparVectors = compare \`on\` vectorLength`

Comment: @pat: which is the definition of `comparing`, bringing us full circle! I find the `comparing` idiom easier to read, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 8):

The Perl people call the following pattern the [Schwartzian_transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

Just change your list into a list of key-value pairs and sort by key. (This avoids extra computations of the key function if it is expensive-ish)

```
sortByKey keyf xs =
    let k_xs = map (\x-> (keyf x, x)) xs in
    let sorted = sortBy (compare `on` fst) k_xs in
    map snd sorted

sortByKey vectorLength vectors
```

Comment: In the perl community, this is known as "Schwartzian Transform", if I remember correctly.

Comment: `map snd.sortBy(comparing fst)$zip (map g lst) lst` ... which was known long before Randal Schwartz. There's also this law about how discoveries always get named after somebody other than their author. This law was also named after somebody else. (I don't remember the name).

Comment: @WillNess: I'd find it surprising if he actually were the original author, given how obvious of a pattern this is. I'm curious what is that other name you are thinking about, since I don't think I have ever heard of it.

Comment: @missingno can't remember! (and can't remember *where* I've seen this, but it **is** hilarious! :)) WP says in Lisp it was known as *decorate-and-sort*; or in general *memoization*.